# ASP.NET 5 MVC with EF controllers using services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I'm new to the ASP.NET 5 MVC with Entity Framework. This is probably a simple problem, but I can't find a tutorial for this online, or I don't know how to search for it. So here's my problem.

I've took the task of finishing a simple project. Here's how the solution looks like:

[image]

Task says that there's this code-first approach, hence the Data, Entity, and Services libraries.

- Data - provides the DataContext
- Entity - provides objects (C# classes that represent DB tables)
- Services - provide CRUD and other functions for each entity

**How do you call service for object A from controller for object B without using the DataContext class?**

All tutorials I've seen don't even use services. Each of their controllers use the DataContext instance. If I used DataContext in my controller for object B I would render services library useless. I know I can, but the goal is to use the services.

It might go without saying for me, but just to be clear: services library has 2 interfaces and 2 classes that implement the two interfaces, one pair of interface-class is for object A and the other is for object B. So: IServiceA, ServiceA, IServiceB, ServiceB.

The reason I need ServiceA to call from ControllerB is because B contains an instance of A, thus for my practice I need to list all As in a view dedicated to B.

Comment: Show us the code, start by showing us the constructor for one controller and one service. Normally the service is injected into the controller and the context is hidden behind the service. But without code, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked and saw that each of the services is using the DataContext, so I could have just added a new function there and continue using the service in the controller.

Silly silly me.

Comment: A controller shouldn't use a DataContext.  It should only use a service.